# How to restrict special characters from an Android EditText field?

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to restrict special characters from an Android EditText field?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Have you tried adding the `android:digits="abcde.....0123456789"` attribute?
Although the `android:digits` specify that it is a numeric field, it does work for me to set it to accept letters as well, and special characters as well (tested on SDK-7).

If this doesn't work then you'll have to implement `KeyListener`
see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setKeyListener(android.text.method.KeyListener)

Comment: This method gives me issue when also using android:imeOptions="actionNext" on ICS devices. The 'Next' button does not show up!!!

Comment: What should the user do if he wants to use other language than english?

Comment: is this case insensitive or sensitive?

Answer (score 6):

Just pass the EditText object to this method. Also add the values that is to be blocked in the variable blockCharacterSet.

```
private void disableSpecialChar(EditText editText) {
      final String blockCharacterSet = "<>";

      InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

       @Override
       public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
         Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        if (source != null && blockCharacterSet.contains(("" + source))) {
         return "";
        }
        return null;
       }
      };

      editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });

     }
```

Comment: user is still able to paste these invalid chars into edittext

Comment: solution is to do check in loop for every character, as it is shown here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7335559/1235910

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem in my answer: [Prevent special symbols in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45413499/6662058). You can change the regex as per your requirement.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16885840)

Comment: Clearly the linked solution shows how to restrict special characters in EditText. This has solved my problem which was same as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Okay, so you flag it as a duplicate if it is already answered with an accepted answer.

Comment: The questions are different. One is asked to solve a bug in Android's widget property while this question is about achieving a requirement. But the solution to both of the questions are same. They cannot (should not) be marked duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Just put below xml line inside edittext block.

```
android:digits="abc"
```

This will allow to enter only a,b and c characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Kotlin version including whitespace:

```
private val userNameFilter =
    InputFilter { source, start, end, dest, dStart, dEnd ->
        for (i in start until end) {
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source[i]) && !Character.isWhitespace(source[i])) {
                return@InputFilter ""
            }
        }
        null
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a class for more flexible settings of input constraints to EditText:

https://github.com/devapro/NumberWatcher

It is implementation only for numbers input, but you can change it for any of the types.