# How to restrict Single Quote in android EditText?

Tags: java, android

friends,

i want to restrict " character in android EditText any one guide me how to achieve this in java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to set an [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) on your EditText object

[This page has an example](http://blog.mobile-j.de/2009/12/i-really-like-androids-edittext.html) of an InputFilter for numeric values

Answer (score 1):

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01)).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
 {           
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
{             
                    //check here if character is '"' if yes don't allow to right
}          
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,  int count) 
{            

}            
@Override        
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
 {             
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub         
 }     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May this solve it?
[How to restrict special characters from an Android EditText field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385631/how-to-restrict-special-charackters-from-an-android-edittext-field)

Answer (score 0):

use the onKeyDown or onTextChanged event