# How to restrict the EditText to accept only alphanumeric characters

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

How can I restrict an `EditText` to accept only alphanumeric characters, with both lowercase and uppercase characters showing as uppercase in the `EditText`?

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userInput"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:minLines="3" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

If a user types in lowercase "abcd", the `EditText` should automatically show uppercase "ABCD" without needing to restrict the keyboard to uppercase.

Comment: editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "));

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validation allow only number and characters in edit text in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192199/validation-allow-only-number-and-characters-in-edit-text-in-android)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

In the XML, add this:

```
 android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "
```

Comment: in this case if i enter any other this will enter multiple character automatically

Comment: is there any way i can restrict user to input only alphabets or single space only.

Comment: @Ravi just remove the numbers? leave the space at the end for the single space

Comment: This doesn't allow uppercase characters, which OP asked for.

Comment: This solution plus `textAllCaps="true"` should do the thing

Comment: What if ,I want to achieve this programmatically?

Comment: @AnuragPandit , please refer this link

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344493/android-how-to-set-acceptable-numbers-and-characters-in-edittext

Comment: WARNING: some mobile phone like samsung J series does not provides `space` key in keyboard if you go with this method. Consider a test on android 6.0.x versions.

Comment: This answer fails for scalability. Please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49399727/1072991

Comment: android:digits breaks imeOptions (namely actionDone).

Answer (score 36):

> How to restrict the EditText to accept only alphanumeric characters only so that whatever lower case or upper case key that the user is typing, EditText will show upper case

The `InputFilter` solution works well, and gives you full control to filter out input at a finer grain level than `android:digits`. The `filter()` method should return `null` if all characters are valid, or a `CharSequence` of only the valid characters if some characters are invalid. If multiple characters are copied and pasted in, and some are invalid, only the valid characters should be kept.

```
public static class AlphaNumericInputFilter implements InputFilter {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

        // Only keep characters that are alphanumeric
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            char c = source.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
                builder.append(c);
            }
        }

        // If all characters are valid, return null, otherwise only return the filtered characters
        boolean allCharactersValid = (builder.length() == end - start);
        return allCharactersValid ? null : builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Also, when setting your `InputFilter`, you must make sure not to overwrite other `InputFilters` set on your `EditText`; these could be set in XML, like `android:maxLength`. You must also consider the order that the `InputFilters` are set, they are applied in that order. Luckily, `InputFilter.AllCaps` already exists, so that applied with our alphanumeric filter will keep all alphanumeric text, and convert it to uppercase.

```
    // Apply the filters to control the input (alphanumeric)
    ArrayList<InputFilter> curInputFilters = new ArrayList<InputFilter>(Arrays.asList(editText.getFilters()));
    curInputFilters.add(0, new AlphaNumericInputFilter());
    curInputFilters.add(1, new InputFilter.AllCaps());
    InputFilter[] newInputFilters = curInputFilters.toArray(new InputFilter[curInputFilters.size()]);
    editText.setFilters(newInputFilters);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I have tried the suggested solutions on this and other pages and only this solution covers all my devices perfectly (Samsung being a particularly annoying one). Some gave me ONLY number input, some just failed to type anything complaining about the initial length of 0 characters on input etc. i would also shorthand the set filters to `editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps(), alphanumericFilter});`

Comment: @ZooS your shorthand would overwrite any existing `InputFilters` already on the `EditText`. Please *read* my explanation right above the code block, setting of the filter is done that way for very specific reasons.

Comment: My bad, didn't quite read through the explanation, you are correct. This is teh best solution in my opinion.

Comment: Didn't work. When the user inputs a non-valid character, the current text on the edit text is doubled !!

Comment: The bug happens when you type two numbers in a row

Comment: @FelipeRibeiroR.Magalhaes Double check your code. If you are having trouble, post a question. I have this code working in multiple production apps.

Comment: This actually accepts another languages too, not only alphabets.

Comment: but it doesn't accept white space, I tried ```if (Character.isLetter(c) || Character.isSpaceChar(' ')) {
        builder.append(c);
      }``` but no luck

Comment: also @FelipeRibeiroR.Magalhaes is right, when you type numbers it appends the current text to the current one, the reason is obviously Stupid Samsung and their horrible phones because it works on other brands

Comment: I need to restrict the mathematical "pi" symbol which is there in google indic keyboard. how can i do that using this approach??

Comment: This answer works best.  I added a Kotlin version similar to this approach here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52712002/5652513.

Comment: "You must also consider the order that the InputFilters are set, they are applied in that order." - I fail to understand why the order is important ?

Comment: @GoranHoriaMihail if you have multiple non-mutually exclusive filters, i.e. a length filter of 10 and an alphanumeric filter, you would want to apply the alphanumeric filter first, then the length of 10 filter. Otherwise, if the length filter is applied first, it would trim to 10, and then may remove more non alphanumeric characters when the alphanumeric filter is applied, incorrectly only applying the alphanumeric filter to the first 10 characters (rather than keeping up to 10 alphanumeric characters). This would come into play when a user pastes text into an EditText from say a PW manager.

Answer (score 22):

If you don't want much of customization a simple trick is actually from the above one with all characters you want to add in android:digits

```
android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
```

This should work to accept alphanumeric values with Caps & Small letters.

Comment: This would fail for multilingual application.

Answer (score 13):

Use this:

```
android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

I tried using `textAllCaps="true"` as suggested in a comment of accepted answer to this question but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: This would fail for multilingual application.

Answer (score 8):

You do not want to write any regular expression for this you can just add XML properties to your Edit text

```
android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

Tested Working Perfectly for PAN Card validation.

Comment: Time saver! Thank you so much.

Comment: Not working correctly. On entering invalid (special) characters it malfunctions.

Answer (score 6):

try This:

```
private void addFilterToUserName()
    {

        sign_up_display_name_et.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                new InputFilter() {
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                                               int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                        if(src.equals("")){ // for backspace
                            return src;
                        }
                        if(src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z 0-9]+")){
                            return src;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }
                }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Minimalist Kotlin approach:

```
fun EditText.allowOnlyAlphaNumericCharacters() {
    filters = filters.plus(
        listOf(
            InputFilter { s, _, _, _, _, _->
                s.replace(Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9]"), "")
            },
            InputFilter.AllCaps()
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: this resulted in a weird bug where after typing something, the edittext is filled with random letters that can't be removed

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/68709480/4091268. Uodated version of above.

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to create your custom Filter and set to your EditText like this.

This will convert your alphabets to uppercase automatically.

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userInput);
InputFilter myFilter = new InputFilter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        try {
            Character c = source.charAt(0);
            if (Character.isLetter(c) || Character.isDigit(c)) {
                return "" + Character.toUpperCase(c);
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
};
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { myFilter });
```

No additional parameters to set in xml file.

Comment: I have used this method for do last character Capital based on some conditions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="PromoCode"
                    android:digits="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789,_,-"
                    android:inputType="text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solution by @[methodSignature](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5652513/methodsignature) but as mentioned by @[Aba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4253952/aba) it is generating the repeated/weird string. So modified it.

Kotlin:

```
fun EditText.allowOnlyAlphaNumericCharacters() {
    filters = arrayOf(
        InputFilter { src, start, end, dst, dstart, dend ->
            if (src.toString().matches(Regex("[a-zA-Z 0-9]+"))) {
                src
            } else ""
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

`android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"`

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically, do this:

```
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
mEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter() {   
        @Override  
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence input, int start, int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) { 
            if (input.length() > 0 && !Character.isLetterOrDigit(input.charAt(0))) {  
                // if not alphanumeric, disregard the latest input
                // by returning an empty string 
                return ""; 
            }
            return null;
        }  
    }, new InputFilter.AllCaps()
});
```

Note that the call to `setInputType` is necessary so that we are sure that the `input` variable is always the last character given by the user.

I have tried other solutions discussed here in SO. But many of them were behaving weird in some cases such as when you have Quick Period `(Tap space bar twice for period followed by space)` settings on. With this setting, it deletes one character from your input text. This code solves this problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final int MAX_LENGTH =13;
```

`et_ScanLotBrCode.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps(),new InputFilter.LengthFilter(MAX_LENGTH) })`;

add above code into activity or fragment, using this you can manage the length of input and uppercase letter.

Comment: The question does not ask about limiting the length. It asks how to restrict the `EditText` to accept only alphanumeric characters and to display them in uppercase.

Answer (score -3):

one line answer

XML Add this textAllCaps="true"

do this onCreate()

**for lower case & upper case with allowing space**

```
yourEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "));
```

**for lower case with allowing space**  ***(Required answer for this question)***

```
yourEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "));
```

**for upper case with allowing space**

```
yourEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 "));
```

Comment: This doesn't allow lowercase characters or numbers, which OP asked for.

Comment: @StevenByle Thanku, for the response. I have edited the answer

Comment: Also,  PLs read the question again : " If a user types in lowercase "abcd", the EditText should automatically show uppercase "ABCD" without needing to restrict the keyboard to uppercase."

Comment: it allow only digits