# Android show only some characters in keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

i have the following problem to resolve in an Android App. I have an editText which has to show only numbers and the the letters 'x' and 'c' when the keyboard is prompted. Is this possible? Thanks for the help!

Comment: check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212439/how-to-restrict-the-edittext-to-accept-only-alphanumeric-characters

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, with *filters* using **InputFilter**.

Here a piece of sample code:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter()
{
     public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
     {
         for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
         {
             if (Character.isDigit(source.charAt(i)) || (source.charAt(i) == 'x') || (source.charAt(i) == 'c'))
             {
                return "";
             }
         }

         return null;
     }
};

editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this doesn't work. It shows all the characters and filters whatever the user enters. I need to show (if possible) only the numbers 0-9 and the letters x and c

Comment: It's not possible, you have to build your own keyboard or using some control fields to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to build your own keyboard or you can restrict input in such a way:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="text"
    android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,xc" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try below properties for your **EditText**

**Example :**

**Alphabet**

```
 android:inputType="text" // for alphabet
```

**you can put your own combination of digits**

```
 android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,*,xc"  // you can put your own combination of digits
```

**Alphanumeric**

```
 android:digits="0123456789 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

**Numeric**

```
 input.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY); // its show only the numeric keyboard.
```

Comment: Thanks Shiva, i will probably use this solution. It wasn't what i expected but hiding the characters is not possible, so this is the best i can do.