# How to allow space on android:digits

Tags: android

I am restricting on Android Edittext as below

android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
but can't enter spaces.  How can I make it allow spaces?  Is this possible to get only via .xml?.

Comment: "but can't able to enter space." - How do you mean, exactly? Are you getting an error when you add a space there, or is it just not working?

Comment: Have you tried adding a space into that string? Look at the accepted answer here.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212439/how-to-restrict-the-edittext-to-accept-only-alphanumeric-characters

Comment: just add the space between any character of your digit like this android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY Z"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this, hope it helps,

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
```

Comment: Sorry, but didn't worked on my case.EditText still restricts the `space`.I was trying on a PIXEL emulator in studio itself.

Comment: @iCantC It works on real devices. Its a very old attribute. Try on real device. Also check if u r trimming the string in code as it wont work.

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly , as you predicted I was actually trimming the text, so tried it  by removing the trim function and it was as smooth as butter.

Answer (score 8):

**Edittext** digit accept white space only if give space end of characters, have look:

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<string name="digits_text">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789@$%^*()_+-{},./\|&amp; </string>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textinputlayout_support_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_or">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textinputedittext_help_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:digits="@string/digits_text"
        android:hint="@string/description"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="6"
        android:maxLines="10" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Digits allowed space in EditText Android.

Answer (score 0):

1. Include space(" ") in end of Digits String

   > "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "

```html
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                        style="@style/Text_input_EditText"
                        android:hint="Enter S/o , D/o , W/o *"
                        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
                        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
                        android:maxLength="100"
                        android:id="@+id/do_ad_so_do_wo"
                        />
```