# Can Nativescript Angular intercept text change event before it happen?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have `TextField` using Angular nativescript.

```
<TextField   (textChange)="onTextChange($event)" ></TextField>
```

I want to allow only the "`a`"  character to be inserted into that TextField.
All other characters  ( "b","c",....) should be prevented - meaning - prevented from inserted.

I already know that I can use the `(textChange)`  event and then delete the char -  but that's a *too late event*.

**Question:**

Assuming I have a textfield , How can I cross-platform prevent certain chars from being entered ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Android, you can do it by explicitly setting the allowed instances for `setKeyListener` of `android.widget.Edittext` (which is the native Android control behind `TextField` in NativeScript)

Foor example

```
export function onTfLoaded(args) {
    let tf = <TextField>args.object;

    let nativeTF;

    if (isAndroid) {
        let nativeTF = <android.widget.EditText>tf.nativeView; // on Android is android.widget.EditText
        nativeTF.setKeyListener(android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("zxc"));
    } else {
        let nativeTF = <UITextField>tf.nativeView;// for iOS is UITextField
    }

}
```

The above is will allow the user to input only ZXC (works the same [as setting digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23212485/4936697)), however, the solution will still prompt a numeric keyboard.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I wish NS would have `(onKeyDown)` where it will have `e` to `e.cancel`....

Comment: you can directly access the native controls (EditText and UITextField) and use the provided event - e.g. `beforeTextChange` event on `EditText` like done here https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/339#issuecomment-336791993 .. for iOS I am not sure if there is similar event but if so you can overwrite the delegate method and use it

Comment: I lost some time on this because I didn't know keyboardType will mess with this. For example I was adding ',' as one of the digits, but wasn't being accepted because I had keyboard="number"