# How to limit text field to only accept certain letters? - Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there a way to limit a text field so that it only accept certain letters from an array?

Let's say I have an array:

```
val array = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
```

I want the list to be manipulated inside code, so that the letters you can type in the text field is changed by code. How do I implement this via a class to make it accept only the letters a, b, or c?

Comment: you can use android:digits inside xml layout of your edittext

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restrict the EditText to accept only alphanumeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212439/how-to-restrict-the-edittext-to-accept-only-alphanumeric-characters)

Comment: I want the list of numbers to be manipulated in code. Is there a way to do that to using xml layout?

Comment: @HUAN5235 there are answers about how to do that using code in that question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this. In XML of edit text you need to use below code

```
android:digits="abc123"
```

Here **abc123** are your required digits you want your edit text should accept. You can also limit to **abc** as your desire. So use below code

```
android:digits="abc"
```

Comment: Is there a way to edit android:digits in kotlin code? It would save me a lot of hassle .

Comment: get reference of that edit text and you can play either way as you can play via xml.

Answer (score 0):

android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

Pass whatever alphabets you want