# How to force EditText to accept only specific alphanumerical characters?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want from my `EditText` to accept only certain characters. I don`t want to filter them in listener, I want to set it in XML permanently.

I want to use only these characters:
`0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ`

So I made string and add that to `android:digits`.
I want to convert each lowercase letter to uppercase (I dont want to disable typing without shift just convert them)

I used `android:textAllCaps="true"` but this doesnt work.

Comment: you can put validation string for this in your class file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, This will help you for sure.

```
 editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in XML file

```
 android:digits="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ"
```

Possible duplicate:
[How to restrict the EditText to accept only alphanumeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212439/how-to-restrict-the-edittext-to-accept-only-alphanumeric-characters)

Comment: It would be nice of you to put this answer as correct.

Comment: He already did that... He wants to capitalize every digit entered.