# How to prevent underlining of typed text and also have all capital letters?

Tags: android

My style for my `TextInputLayout`

```
<style name="inputText" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/neon_blue</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">textVisiblePassword|textCapCharacters</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

has `inputType`

```
textVisiblePassword|textCapCharacters
```

I have `textCapCharacters` to make text all caps. I have `textVisiblePassword` to prevent key board from underlining text as it is typed.

`textVisiblePassword` overrides `textCapCharacters` because passwords are case sensitive.

How can I prevent underlining of typed text and also have all caps?

**edit**

`textNoSuggestions` does not remove underline from typing which is why I added `textVisiblePassword` but `textVisiblePassword` appears to override `textCapCharacters` because (I think) that passwords are enforced to be case sensitive.

Comment: I think it's easier to understand the problem if you post screenshot.

Comment: In editText inputType =textCapCharacters will not work..you have to set this programatically..see my answer below..hope it will b helpful

Answer (score 0):

To prevent key board from underlining text, you have to use textNoSuggestions. Use your style like this -

```
<style name="inputText" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/neon_blue</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">textVisiblePassword|textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Does the keyboard underline the text of the system? Seems interesting.

Comment: That is the suggestion, i guess

Comment: I am just pointing out that the system does the text to be underlined not the keyboard I think or I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is..Follow the attachhed link to allow all characters in Uppercase programatically.
[How to force EditText to accept only specific alphanumerical characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56495984/how-to-force-edittext-to-accept-only-specific-alphanumerical-characters/56503653#56503653) and give inputType `textVisiblePassword`