# Validation not to take Special Character only character in Uppercase

Tags: android, validation

I want to restrict special character when user type on edittext, how I can achieve it, I tried:

```
public boolean validateBuisnessName(EditText et, String name, TextInputLayout textInputLayout) {
  String alphaRegex = ".*[A-Z0-9].*";

  // Check if pattern matches
  if (name.matches(alphaRegex)) {
     textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
  } else {
     textInputLayout.setError("Invalid Buisness Name");
     return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude special characters from android keypad for EditText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335455/how-to-exclude-special-characters-from-android-keypad-for-edittext)

Comment: how to check the validation?