# how to avoid characters like �‎ in an edittext?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an issue when user try to enter text copied that this text sometimes contains some special characters like �

and this make JSON string to be not formated, so please how can I avoid user enter such characters

please take into consideration that user can enter Arabic text and English text only

Comment: Your json problem is probably unrelated to the char that are entered. Better show some code related to your problem if you want it solved.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix the JSON problem is not my side, it is server side, the server API crash when user enter such characters, so I do not have any codes for this problem, I just want to avoid any characters except [Arabic Alphabet, English Alphabet, Numbers]

Comment: Looks like an **encoding** problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using InputFilters on the Edittext:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                   Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (isEnglishOrArabicChar(source.charAt(i))) {
                    stringBuilder.append(source.charAt(i));
                }
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    };
etName.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});

private static boolean isEnglishOrArabicChar(char c) {
    Character.UnicodeBlock ub = Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c);
    return ub == Character.UnicodeBlock.ARABIC || ub==Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN;
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335455/how-to-exclude-special-characters-from-android-keypad-for-edittext)

Comment: I have tried your code, the edittext is not accepting any characters

Comment: Edited the code, the if condition was the opposite. Now it should work!

Comment: it is working now , but why can not I paste text to edittext ?

Comment: I can paste text on my edittext which has the filter attached. Just long tap on the edittext and paste.

Comment: I did long press and when click paste, nothing happen and no text appear in my edittext , my android os is 7.0 and device type is Samsung s6 edge

Comment: I edited again to fit your needs. Now I check char by char and build the result accordingly. Let me know if its working.