# Validations in android/eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, validation

How to restrict an edittextbox with numbers and special symbols on android/eclipse.

ie., i must want to allow only the characters (a-z & A-Z) not the others.

Is there any options available to do this through .xml(file)?

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to restrict special characters from an Android EditText field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385631/how-to-restrict-special-characters-from-an-android-edittext-field) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361497/how-to-create-edittext-accepts-alphabets-only-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

//ya its avilable

in your string.xml you can add and resource as

```
<string name="specific_chars">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz _1234567890</string>
```

and access in your edit text add attribute as

```
android:digits="@string/specific_chars"
```

now only the specified characters only edittext will take.