# Edit text should take both characters and numbers

Tags: java, android

I have an `EditText` box and I want the default keyboard that should come up when it is selected to be the alphabetic keypad, since most of the time users will be entering alphabetic characters.

However, I also want to allow users to enter numbers too, if they need to. Using android:inputType="text" restricts input to characters only. What options do I have?

Comment: did u try not to specify the type?

Comment: android:digits="@string/specific_chars" http://stackoverflow.com/a/10929070/1012284

Comment: It did the work. Thank you Jamp.

Answer (score 0):

android:inputType="text" was not supposed to block numbers to be inserted, anyway, you can always use the "|".

Take a look at the docs.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Answer (score 0):

Put this on your layout:

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,0123456789"
```

Those will be the only allowed symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in layout:

```
 android:digits="@string/edittextDigit"
```

and string.xml

```
 <string name="edittextDigit">qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmQWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM</string>
```

So, users can enter characters specified by you.