# I have an EditText for math expressions and want the default number keyboard to pop up

Tags: android, keyboard

I have an EditText with inputType = text, because a math expression can be entered.
I would like to have a keyboard that shows numbers along with +, %, - and *.
Not sure what that kind of keyboard is called.
Is there a way for me to set it up without having to change inputType to number.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
    android:digits="0123456789.+-*/%()"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:inputType="phone"
  android:digits="0123456789.+-*/"
  android:id="@+id/inputs"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting input type to your EditText

```
<EditText android:inputType="number" ... />
```

**EDIT**

There's another option for better customization [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736040/edittext-allow-only-specific-characters-known-from-context)

Comment: Will that allow me to enter * () + % if I do?

Comment: Added link to another option

Answer (score 0):

[**AndroidDoc**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) Use the inputType `numberDecimal|numberSigned` for calculator

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned" >

</EditText>
```