# How can restrict my EditText input to some special character like backslash(/),tild(~) etc by soft keyboard in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, character, android-softkeyboard

I am developing an application for keyboard, but i am geting an issue.
I want to restrict/block some special character from soft keyboard in EditText in android programmatically.

So, Is there any way I can restrict any special character input in edit text in android?

Comment: android:digits="~/\#^|"

Comment: which special characters you want to restrict;

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try this may work for you

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editText;
    private String blockCharacterSet = "~#^|$%&*!";

    private InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            if (source != null && blockCharacterSet.contains(("" + source))) {
                return "";
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
    }

}
```

Comment: Its works fine,but i need more help.How can restrit the the currency symbol like £,€ etc.

Comment: Add Character That You Want To Restrict in blockCharacterSet @jagdish

Comment: Thnx Biraj  -- How to block "(double quotes) charctaer?

Comment: @Sanket990 you can use \" for that.

Comment: user is still able to paste these invalid chars into edittext

Comment: solution is to do check in loop for every character, as it is shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7335559/1235910

Comment: I want on Mobile number Edit text first letter start with  7 , 8 , 9 Digits  only  how to restrict 1234560 digits in first character of edit text

Comment: yabut I can still copy and paste naughty characters in!

Comment: Watch out, since this solution has given me mixed results. It blocked typing of everything, except when I tried typing two hashtags (#) in sequence. Weird behavior. Probably you will be better of using the `android:digits` or just checking at on singular point (e.g. after button press) for input field validity.

Comment: to help handle `copy-pasted` case, can utilize `filter` as well, can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70361005/10467286

Answer (score 43):

If you want to add spaces you can give space after the last digit.

```
  android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm "
```

Comment: If You add space in last digit it won't consider. If you wanna give space then give it in between the digits or alphabets. don't give it, in the end and at the start.

Comment: @tara You can put any where with in double quotes(" "). that is worked for me.

Answer (score 30):

This should work:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) { 
                                return ""; 
                        } 
                } 
                return null; 
        } 
}; 

edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Or if you prefer the easy way:

```
<EditText android:inputType="text" android:digits="0123456789*,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm" />
```

Comment: actually u don't have to specify comma

Answer (score 20):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385631/how-to-restrict-special-characters-from-an-android-edittext-field) link which shows **How to restrict special characters from an Android EditText field?**

Try this code 
`android:digits="abcde.....012345789"` i guess this is the easiest way to do.Hope this help you.

Comment: it blocks single & double quotes, space

Answer (score 16):

Its late but may be helpfull for others.
Instead of programaticaly, you can go with xml attribute. It may be the case that in Single layout you have many editText, out of which you wanna restrict special characters only in one EditText. So defining in xml will help you out. Here is the code to restrict special Characters by allowing them to only enter alphabets and numbers like below

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/editText"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="@dimen/text10"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:maxLength="16"
     android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

For those who might be facing issues while adding space please add a blank space with all the alphabets. Below is an example 
Also you should know that user won't be able to add a new line in this case.

```
            <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:digits="0123456789,a bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

Answer (score 5):

First need to add DigitsKeyListener for allowing characters and then setRawInputType to edittext field

```
edit_field.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"));


edit_field.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);
```

Comment: this help me because it works with pastes

Answer (score 2):

you can prevent for typing special character:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      CharSequence previous;
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(s.toString().contains("&^%$#*&(")){
              s.clear();
              s.append(previous.toString());
        }
      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {    
            previous = s;
      }

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer still allows the user paste in unwanted characters. This solution works:

---

**All you have to do is this:**

```
List<String> unwantedChars = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("@", "€"));
editText.addTextChangedListener(new FilterUnwantedChars(editText, unwantedChars));
```

**Helper class:**

```
public class FilterUnwantedChars implements TextWatcher {

    private List<String> unwantedChars;
    private EditText editText;

    private boolean listenToTextChange;

    public FilterUnwantedChars(EditText editText, List<String> unwantedChars) {
        this.unwantedChars = unwantedChars;
        this.editText = editText;
        this.listenToTextChange = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (!listenToTextChange) {
            listenToTextChange = true;
            return;
        }

        String result = s.toString();
        final String oldString = result;
        for (String unwanted : unwantedChars) {
            result = result.replace(unwanted, "");
        }

        if (!oldString.equals(result)) {
            listenToTextChange = false;
            int currentPos = editText.getSelectionStart()-1;
            editText.setText(result);

            try {
                editText.setSelection(currentPos);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

    public void setEditText(EditText editText) {
        this.editText = editText;
    }

    public EditText getEditText() {
        return editText;
    }

    public List<String> getUnwantedChars() {
        return unwantedChars;
    }

    public void setUnwantedChars(List<String> unwantedChars) {
        this.unwantedChars = unwantedChars;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the accepted solution doesn't work in all the cases. The proper solution would be to use the following `InputFilter`:

```
private InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    // An example pattern that restricts the input only to the lowercase letters
    private static final Pattern restrictedChars = Pattern.compile("[a-z]*")

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        final CharSequence replacementText = source.subSequence(start, end);
        final CharSequence replacedText = dest.subSequence(dstart, dend);

        if (source == null || restrictedChars.matcher(replacementText).matches()) {
            return null; // Accept the original replacement
        }

        return replacedText; // Keep the original text
    }
};
```

This solution differs from the accepted one in that it solves the following problems:

- only a subsequence of the source is the replacement, not the full source
- source doesn't necessarily include only the newly typed text, sometimes it is the full text typed so-far

Answer (score 0):

kotlin version of this answer

```
class NameActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  var myFilter = InputFilter { source, _, _, _, _, _ ->
        try {
            val c = source[0]
            return@InputFilter if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)  || c == '_' || c == '.' || c == ' ')
                c.toString()
            else
                ""
        } catch (e: Exception) { }
        null
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_name)
        val edittext = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext)
        edittext.filters = (arrayOf(myFilter))
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please share for jetpack compose ??

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
android:digits="÷×=%_-+#().,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzA BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890\n\u0020"
```

for space use:

```
\u0020
```

for new line use:

```
\n
```

for ime options use:

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Hope it works for you...

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved by using `filters`, i.e.

```
val regex = Regex("^[~#^|$%&*!]*$")
val filter = InputFilter { source, _, _, _, _, _ ->
    return@InputFilter when {
        source?.matches(regex) == true -> ""
        else -> null
    }
}
editText.filters = arrayOf(filter)
```

and for handling `copy-pasted` text, can be done by adding condition to check if text inputted was greater than `1`, which now looks like this

```
val regex = Regex("^[~#^|$%&*!]*$")
val filter = InputFilter { source, _, _, _, _, _ ->
    return@InputFilter when {
        source?.matches(regex) == true -> ""
        source.length > 1 -> source.trim { it.toString().matches(regex) } // Put your desired logic here, these sample logic was doing a trim/remove
        else -> null
    }
}
editText.filters = arrayOf(filter)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to restrict any key from virtual input inside EditText. We achieve this with XML or JAVA/Kotlin. Below is the code with XML:

```
    <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzA BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890\n\u0020"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

Above code for Name Field restricts all the special characters.
We Show another example for a Description/Message/Feedback.

```
 <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                     android:digits=".,?:/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzA BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890\n\u0020"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

That means simply adding digits which are included.