# How to allow only some characters in android `edittext` control

Tags: android, android-edittext

in the below `EditText` I want to allow some characters like `@, -, _, . (dot)` remaining characters I don't want to allow to enter. Even want to block smiley's.

Can any one help me?

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/emailId"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:background="@color/transperent"
     android:hint="@string/email_id" 
     android:digits="0123456789*qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm_-." 
     android:inputType="text"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:padding="8dp"
     android:textColor="@color/white"
     android:textColorHint="@color/white" />
```

Comment: Why don't you add that characters in `android:digits`

Answer (score 0):

You can try use digits and just put there every char that you allow , for example all the english chars:

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "
```

Comment: that is not a issue for example while your enter a emailid i dont want to allow some character like *,&,$,# etc i want to block some characters

Comment: lets say for example when the user is entering # char you want to disable it ?

Comment: yes. but instead of disable some characters .want to allow some characters this is good i guess

Comment: Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21828520/8274756) , it may help you

Answer (score 0):

Build.gradle (Module:app)

```
dependencies{
        compile 'com.xw.repo:xedittext:2.0.0@aar'
    }
```

XML:

```
<com.xw.repo.XEditText
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm_-." //Digits specific
    app:x_disableEmoji="true"/> // Disable Emoticons
```

I hope it helps