# How to Enable/Disable individual Keys in android soft keyboards? or enable/disable state of keys

Tags: android, keyboard, android-source

Could not find any attribute for disable/enable individual keys in Keyboard.Key in Android.How to disable individual keys in android programmatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can restrict my EditText input to some special character like backslash(/),tild(~) etc by soft keyboard in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828323/how-can-restrict-my-edittext-input-to-some-special-character-like-backslash-t)

Comment: No, Want to enable/disable a set of character keys from keyboard.
QWERTY ... example i want to disable keys WER and enable keys QTY.

Comment: You can't.  There is no API to control the keyboard like that.  All you can do is ignore text when it isn't a key you want.  Also, no real keyboard uses Keyboard.Key, Keyboard, or Keyboard.View-  not even Google's.  They're too simplistic and limiting.