# How to restrict user from typing special characters in Search view Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, search, special-characters, searchview

I have to restrict users from typing Special Characters in the Search view.

I have already defined the input type as textPersonName, but the users should not be able to type any Special Characters in the first place.

When I tried to cast it to an EditText. It throws an exception, as below:

```
  val filter: InputFilter = object : InputFilter {
            override fun filter(
                source: CharSequence,
                start: Int,
                end: Int,
                dest: Spanned?,
                dstart: Int,
                dend: Int
            ): CharSequence? {
                for (i in start until end) {
                    if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source[i])) {
                        return ""
                    }
                }
                return null
            }
        }
        var etSearch = searchview_filter as EditText
        etSearch.filters = arrayOf(filter)
    

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sbi.investtap, PID: 12227
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828323/how-can-restrict-my-edittext-input-to-some-special-character-like-backslash-t

Comment: check this answer. it may help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21828323/how-can-restrict-my-edittext-input-to-some-special-character-like-backslash-t)

Answer (score 1):

This may help you, you need to check your input when users typing data. You need to set your validation inside filter.

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

fetch `editText from searchview` like this; No need to change edittext's `id`, because it is default android id of Search EditText.

```
var etSearch = searchview_filter.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text) as EditText
etSearch.filters = arrayOf(filter)
```

Comment: No, setFilters() function is not available for the searchView.

Comment: @SwetaJain, need to get edittext from searchview. then apply this filter on that edit text.

Comment: can you explain that with code?

Comment: @SwetaJain check edited answer

Comment: It fails with an exception. 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sbi.investtap, PID: 12227
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Comment: you are doing some mistake here.. set your searchview name on place of 'yourSearchView'... all others details will be same. dont change id, its default android id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245414/discussion-between-sweta-jain-and-bhoomika-patel).

Comment: thanks I got your point .

Comment: @SwetaJain glad that this helps you. can you please accept answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you may achieve this in Kotlin:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
            Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};


   var etSearch = searchview_filter.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text) as EditText
        etSearch.filters = arrayOf(filter)
```